# ASP.NET How Set Variable Value in a Function

Tags: asp.net

So I have 2 variables I.e.

```
Public statusId As String = String.Empty
Public orderDescription As String = String.Empty
```

And I want to set their values within a function, this is what I tried

```
Public Function GetOrderDetails(ByVal statusId As String, ByVal orderDescription As String, ByVal orderID As String, ByVal userID As String) As String

    Dim conn As New DBConnection()
    Dim sql_UserAttempts As SqlCommand = conn.SetStoredProcedure("spOrderDetailsByUserId")

    DBConnection.AddNewParameter(sql_UserAttempts, "@order_ID", ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType.Int, orderID)
    DBConnection.AddNewParameter(sql_UserAttempts, "@user_ID", ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType.Int, userID)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim reader_attempts As SqlDataReader = sql_UserAttempts.ExecuteReader()
        If reader_attempts.HasRows Then
            While reader_attempts.Read()
                statusId = reader_attempts("statusId").ToString()
                orderDescription = reader_attempts("ud_orderDescription").ToString()
            End While
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        M1Utils.ErrorHandler(ex)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
    Return statusId
End Function
```

But when I print out their values after the function they still blank so I was wondering what type of functinon i should use i.e. sub function,.. to do this ?

Called like this

```
            '# Retrieve Order Information
        GetOrderDetails(statusId, orderDescription, orderID, userID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your function like this

```
Public Function GetOrderDetails(ByRef statusId As String, ByRef orderDescription As String, ByVal orderID As String, ByVal userID As String) As String
```

Comment: Ah sweet didnt know about the ByRef, ByVal thing..great solved my problem

Comment: You should read more about ByRef or ByVal if you didn't know about it.